# A simple text is appearing on emulator but not appearing on device

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying a very simple application that is displaying two text field and a button (background color changed).

This is appearing fine on Emulator but when i am trying the same on actual device, one text field is not displaying and button color changed to standard color.

Any quick help ?

Regards,
Gul

**XML**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/enter_phone_number"
    android:id="@+id/EnterNumberMsg"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textColor="#c816365c"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:password="false"
    android:background="#fa538dd5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LogoMsg"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
```

---

Comment: Check your textColor and background color might be same. And for better understanding post your xml

Comment: Try reinstalling the app on your phone, you might run old version of it.

Comment: No background color is not same.. :)

Comment: Tried many times to re-install..

Comment: added xml in my original post.. 9

Comment: need to check your full xml.

Comment: Put it in a code snippet (4 spaces in front) so the markup doesnt get recognized.

Comment: issue resolved, it was due to same xml file name (the previous version of xml file was picking by default). I deleted the previous xml file (created with same name) and now it is working fine.

Comment: Oh great, next time be cautious on layout names and view ids :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your margin from 100 dp to some other low value..because as you said its not visible, size of your cell is smaller than your emulator.